# Is there a lower bound for the following rational expression, in terms of $b^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

In the following, $b$ and $r$ are both positive integers.

Is there a lower bound for the following rational expression, in terms of $b^2$?

$$L = \frac{b^2\left(2^{r+1} b^2(2^r-1) + 3\cdot 2^r - 2\right)}{\left(2^{r+1} - 1\right)(2^r b^2 + 1)}$$

What I do know is that (a crude upper bound is) $L < b^2$.  My question:  Is it possible to get a lower bound for $L$ in terms of $b^2$ alone?

Edit:  Here is an attempt to derive a (crude) lower bound for $L$, using no more than $r \geq 1$ and the AM-GM Inequality.

Since $r \geq 1$, the numerator of $L$ is

$$b^2\left(2^{r+1} b^2(2^r-1) + 3\cdot 2^r - 2\right) \geq 4b^4 + 4b^2 = 4{b^2}(b^2 + 1).$$

Now, for the denominator of $L$, we use the AM-GM Inequality to get

$$\left(2^{r+1} - 1\right)(2^r b^2 + 1) \leq \frac{\left(2^{r+1} + 2^r b^2\right)^2}{4}.$$

Simplifying, we obtain

$$\left(2^{r+1} - 1\right)(2^r b^2 + 1) \leq \left(2^r + 2^{r-1} b^2\right)^2 < 2^{2r}(b^2 + 1)^2.$$

Consequently, I finally have:

$$L > \frac{2^{2-2r}\cdot{b^2}}{b^2 + 1}$$

which is still expressed in terms of the extra variable $r$.

I was wondering if anybody out there has any bright ideas on how to eliminate $r$ from a (hopefully) *nontrivial* lower bound for $L$, in terms of $b^2$.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking of writing the lower bound for $L$ as:

$$\frac{2^{2-2r}\cdot{b^2}}{b^2 + 1} = \frac{2^{2-2r}\cdot{b^2} + 2^{2-2r} - 2^{2-2r}}{b^2 + 1} = 2^{2-2r} - \frac{2^{2-2r}}{b^2 + 1}.$$

Comment: Perhaps I made an error, but it seems to me that $b^2$ is actually a lower bound, not an upper bound.

Comment: @MattSamuel, can you write out your argument for your claim that $b^2$ is actually a lower bound as an actual answer, so that I may be able to review it?  Thanks!

Comment: If I assume to the contrary that $L < b^2$, then I get the following inequality after collecting like terms and simplifying:

$$2^r - 1 < {2^r}{b^2}.$$

This inequality is trivially true.  Therefore, $L < b^2$ is true.

Comment: Another way to see this is to assume to the contrary that $L >= b^2$.  The by-product is:

$$2^r - 1 \geq {2^r}{b^2} \geq 2^r,$$

since $b$ is a positive integer.  This is a contradiction.  Therefore, $L < b^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking off from [Matt](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/187867)'s answer, I get:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{2^r}{2^r - 1}\right)(b^2 + 2^{-r}).$$

We need an upper bound for $\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{2^r}{2^r - 1}\right)$.

We have the upper bound:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{2^r}{2^r - 1}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(2 + \frac{1}{2^r - 1}\right) \leq \frac{3}{2}$$

since $r$ is a positive integer (and hence we can take $r \geq 1$).

Consequently, we now have the (adjusted) lower bound:

$$\frac{b^2\left(2^{r+1} b^2(2^r-1) + 3\cdot 2^r - 2\right)}{\left(2^{r+1} - 1\right)(2^r b^2 + 1)}=\frac{2^{r+1}(2^r-1)b^4 + (3\cdot 2^r - 2)b^2}{\left(2^{r+1} - 1\right)2^r(b^2 + 2^{-r})}=\frac{b^4 + \frac{3\cdot 2^r - 2}{2^{r+1}(2^r-1)}b^2}{\left(1 +\frac{2^r}{2^r-1}\right)(\frac{1}{2}b^2 + 2^{-r-1})}\geq \left(\frac{2}{3}{b^2}\right)\frac{b^2+3\cdot 2^{-r-1}- \frac{1}{2^{r}(2^r-1)}}{b^2+2^{-r}}\geq \left(\frac{2}{3}{b^2}\right)\frac{b^2+2^{-r}+2^{-r-1}-2^{-2r+1}}{b^2+2^{-r}}\geq \frac{2b^2}{3}.$$

I hope what I have written is correct!  =)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{b^2\left(2^{r+1} b^2(2^r-1) + 3\cdot 2^r - 2\right)}{\left(2^{r+1} - 1\right)(2^r b^2 + 1)}=\frac{2^{r+1}(2^r-1)b^4 + (3\cdot 2^r - 2)b^2}{\left(2^{r+1} - 1\right)2^r(b^2 + 2^{-r})}=\frac{b^4 + \frac{3\cdot 2^r - 2}{2^{r+1}(2^r-1)}b^2}{\left(1 +\frac{2^r}{2^r-1}\right)(\frac{1}{2}b^2 + 2^{-r-1})}\geq b^2\frac{b^2+3\cdot 2^{-r-1}- \frac{1}{2^{r}(2^r-1)}}{b^2+2^{-r}}\geq b^2\frac{b^2+2^{-r}+2^{-r-1}-2^{-2r+1}}{b^2+2^{-r}}\geq b^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Matt.  How did you arrive at the first $\geq$ inequality?  I can comprehend your manipulations in the numerator but I seem to see an error in getting a bound for

$$\left(1 + \frac{2^r}{2^r - 1}\right).$$

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris you are right. I did add a disclaimer that perhaps I was in error! Maybe it's fixable to get what you want, though.

Comment: Thanks anyway!  +1 for your effort.  I'll try to see if any results can be salvaged from your last equality.  =)